# AdMob SmartBanner in Xamain Forms Grid with Auto height not showing up

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

I created a Hello World Xamarin Forms app and added code to add AdMob Smart Banner ad following [this](https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/) tutorial. This was working fine until I received an email from AdMob saying "Restricted Ad Serving". So I pulled out my old code gave it a run in Emulator, and the ad wasn't showing up at all, not even the white space(although I can still see blank space in the App Store version).

So I created a blank 'Hello World' app followed the same tutorial. The Ad didn't showed up at all. I verified everything.

XAML -

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ctrl:GoogleAdView Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Then just out of curiosity I specified some random height to the Ad row and voila Ad shows up.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ctrl:GoogleAdView Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Below are the details of my project (Android) -

[image: NuGet packages list for Xamarin Forms Android project]

Is something changed in how we use AdMob in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: In that tutorial, the author also said you may need to set a HeightRequest="90" to have it show up. I found several similar problems and fire an issue then.

Comment: What's troubling is, it is working fine for all of my apps with height `Auto`. However, as soon as I run it locally NOW, its stops showing.

Comment: Are those apps using the package with the same version as the local app?

Comment: Yeah after I published them on App Store never touched the code. Recently I opened them again and just changed the android version to latest pie, everything else is exact same.

Comment: That sounds strange, no idea what happend, maybe it is different under release or debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always had to set a `Height` on my smart banner control. My layout is a bit different since I have my ad control inside of a `ViewCell` but the height logic should be similar for your `RowDefinition.Height`. Try the following method (I use Xamarin.Essentials plugin to get access to `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo` but there are other ways to get these values)

```
    public static int GetSmartBannerHeight() {
        DisplayInfo metrics = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

        double heightDp = metrics.Height / metrics.Density;

        if (heightDp <= 400) {
            return 32;
        }

        if (heightDp <= 720) {
            return 50;
        }

        return 90;
    }
```

Comment: I agree with your method. However, I am still not convinced we need to specify height for banner. Because every example available on internet set `Auto` for SmartBanner. I'll wait for some more time, if nothing works I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: @GauravMathur Yes, I hope someone has a better solution.

Comment: Finally, I got rid of `Auto`, seems like only solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great. The problem comes when there is no internet connectivity. You are left with a blank space. To solve this, consider using the plugin called **Xam.Plugin.Connectivity**. You can use it to check for connection status during initialization and also handle **ConnectivityChanged** event to help you set the height to zero if there is no internet connectivity or appropriate height if the device is connected. Also note that you need to enable these two android permissions: **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** and **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE**. You can enable them at: Right click the android project > Properties > Android Manifest > Required permissions.  Example:

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
        AdContainer.HeightRequest = //Set appropriate height;
    }
    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += ConnectionHasChanged;
}


private void ConnectionHasChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsConnected)
    {
        AdContainer.HeightRequest = //Set appropriate height;
    }
    else
    {
        AdContainer.HeightRequest = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but you can also use the error callback on the ad control itself to determine when to set the height to 0 or not. This will cover both connection issues and other issue such as AdMob fill rate issues.

Comment: Its recommended to allocate a fixed space for the banner ad. If you change container height, users may click on the ad accidentally instead of the actual app content.

Comment: @Márcio Souza Júnior you're right. However, it depends on the app. If the content has enough clearance then there should be no problem.